# How do I change '|' to '-' in HTML page title?

Tags: 7

I wan to change the HTML page title: It is displayed as "pagename | sitename"; I want to change it to "sitename - pagename."

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $Title = explode('|',$head_title);
echo $Title[1]." - ".$Title[0];
?>
```

Add this in the html.tp.php file, inside the `<title>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

I would have used existing `$head_title_array` variable like this:

```
<title><?php print $head_title_array['name'] . ' - ' . $head_title_array['title']; ?></title>
```

Reference: [html.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!html.tpl.php/7)

You can also do this with the [Metatag module](http://drupal.org/project/metatag).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Page Title module](http://drupal.org/project/page_title). After installing it, you can access the configuration page of the module by navigating to:

- Drupal 6: Administer › Site configuration › Page title
- Drupal 7: Administration › Configuration › Search and metadata